# Hashed or random values getting inserted in google cloud datastore

Tags: python-2.7, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

```
task = datastore.Entity(client.key('ModelDataTest', prod_id))
        task.update({
            'ProductId': '1234',
            'ListOfRankedRelevantItems.ProductId': ['345', '456','567'],
            'ListOfRankedRelevantItems.SimilarityScore': ['0.98', '0.89','0.77']
        })
        client.put(task)
```

Using the above code I'm creating an entity in GC-datastore
however I'm getting prod_id as blob like 'MTIzNDU=' instead of string '1234' and ProductId as ["MzIx","MzQ1","NDU2"] instead of ['345', '456','567'] and SimilarityScore as ["MC45OA==","MC44Nw==","MC43Nw=="] instead of ['0.98', '0.89','0.77'] any one having any idea why so and how to get the proper values.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in python 2 string is represented as bytestream and you have to convert it to unicode to see the results properly in gcloud datastore.
Simply use unicode() method to solve this issue.